# sdelete throwing error when used in batch file

Tags: batch-file

I need a batch file that will pull file names, with paths, from a text file; then copy the file to an external drive, then securely delete the file. Everything about this batch file works except sdelete. It throws an error that obviously suggests the path and file name was not enclosed in quotes. As you can see in the batch file, however, it is. The exact same file works perfectly using **del** instead of **sdelete**. Any ideas?

[image]

```
@echo off

set Source=D:\files.txt
set Destination=D:\Reclamation

SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%a in ('type "%Source%"') do (
 IF not exist "%Destination%%%~pa" md "%Destination%%%~pa"
 xcopy /shrkvy "%%a" "%Destination%%%~pa"
 IF NOT !ErrorLevel! EQU 0 (echo "%%a">>"Errors.txt") else (sdelete64 -q -z "%%a")
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Microsoft's documentation: [Sdelete documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sdelete)

```
Usage: sdelete [-p passes] [-r] [-s] [-q] <file or directory> [...]
sdelete [-p passes] [-z|-c [percent free]] <drive letter [...]
```

So `-q` is undocumented but appears incompatible with `-z`

`-z` requires a drive **LETTER**, not a target file/directory.

Comment: Huge thanks. Getting rid of the switches did the trick.